# Cómo eliminar columnas repetidas en un csv y concatenar valores no repetidos de una columna en Python

Tags: python, csv

Primero que nada, buen día!
Tengo un archivo csv con la siguiente estructura:

[image: Tabla Original]

Lo que deseo es eliminar las filas duplicadas que contengan el mismo valor en la columna CODIGO pero concatenar el contenido de la columna NOTAS de cada una de las columnas duplicadas, es decir, si la columna CODIGO tiene el valor de 200000004 repetido 5 veces, quedarse con todo el contenido de la primera fila pero concatenar en esa misma el dato de la columna nota para cada uno de los registros duplicados.

Así es como pretendo que queden los registros:con la columna de NOTAS concatenada:

[image: Tabla Concatenada]

Actualmente estoy utilizando como referencia este código:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import sys
DELIMITER = ','

def remove_duplicates(records):
    prev = None
    for r in records:
        r = (str(r[0]), str(r[1]), str(r[2]), str(r[3]), str(r[4]))
        if prev is None:
            prev = r
        elif r[0] != prev[0]:
            yield prev
            prev = r
        elif r[3] > prev[3]:
            prev = r
    if prev is not None:
        yield prev

def main():
    for r in remove_duplicates(
        l.rstrip('\n').rsplit(DELIMITER) for l in sys.stdin
    ):
        print(*r, sep=',')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Pero no logro hacer que me concatene la parte de las notas, estoy utilizando Python 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
def join_duplicates(input_file, output_file):
    repeated_cod = None # CODIGO (e.g. "20000004").
    repeated_data = None # resto de los datos (e.g. [ "01/01/2020", "SAN JUAN DE VIÑA", "503017", ["SOLICITUD DE INGRESO", "SOLICITUD DE INGRESO", ...] ])

    for line in input_file:
        data = line.rstrip("\n").split(",")
        cod = data[0]
        if (cod == repeated_cod) and (data[4] != ""): # recolectando columna NOTAS para un mismo CODIGO
            repeated_data[3].append( data[4] )
        else:
            if (repeated_cod != None):
                output_file.write(
                    "%s,%s,\"%s\"\n" % (repeated_cod, ",".join(repeated_data[0:3]), ",".join(repeated_data[3]))
                    # e.g.: 20000004,01/01/2020,SAN JUAN DE VIÑA,503017,"SOLICITUD DE INGRESO,SOLICITUD DE INGRESO,SOLICITUD DE INGRESO,..."
                )
            repeated_cod = cod
            repeated_data = list(data[1:])
            repeated_data[3] = [ repeated_data[3] ]

def main():
    #from sys import stdin as inFile
    inFile = open("in.csv", "rt")
    #from sys import stdout as outFile
    outFile = open("out.csv", "wt")
    join_duplicates(inFile, outFile)

if (__name__ == '__main__'):
    main()
```

Hola! Este código (python3), para filas sucesivos con mismo CODIGO, concatena las cosas de la columna NOTAS separándolos con comas.

Comment: Hola, fyi un csv puede tener un registro con una coma adentro si los registros los pones entre comillas, por ejemplo `"columna1","col,um,na2","columna,3"`

Comment: Vaya, cierto, buena aclaración.